# how to export a blender file with a lot of animations?

Tags: export

I've been working on a project involving around 40 animations in Blender, but I've hit a roadblock when attempting to export the Blender file to Godot. Unfortunately, both the FBX and GLTF formats seem to freeze and crash the moment I click the export button. It's becoming quite a hindrance to my workflow. I've considered the possibility of purchasing a new computer, but before taking such a drastic step, I'm wondering if there are any alternative solutions or troubleshooting steps I can explore to overcome this export issue. How can I go about resolving this problem and successfully export my animations to Godot without encountering these crashes?

Comment: Why not export to two files instead of one? Anyway, if you duplicate the blend file, you can delete animations 21 to 40 from the original and animations 1 to 20 from the duplicate. This way, you will end up with two blend files with 20 unique animations each. You can export 20 animations in one go, right?

Comment: @MrA obvious solution that i tried first, didn't work for what i need, loading the animations manually onto the gltf file in godot doesn't work, the skeleton doesn't recognize the animations that were imported later. for now my Solution was to try 3 times and wait 20-40 minutes each time hoping nothing crashes... on the third attempt after like almost 2 hours, i exproted it.